# L'homme-peuple. (Les Misérables)

Tags: vocabulaire

> Despote, mais dictateur, despote résultant d’une république et résumant une révolution. Napoléon devint pour lui **l’homme-peuple** comme Jésus est *l’homme-Dieu.*

Que signifie le mot 'homme-peuple' dans ce contexte ?

Source: [Les Misérables/Tome 3/Livre 3/06](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/06)

Answer (score 4):

Si je me souviens bien de mes cours de catéchisme, Jésus n'est pas Dieu, il est un homme. Il est l'**incarnation de Dieu** parmi les hommes.

De la même manière, Napoléon est ici vu comme l'**incarnation du peuple**, il le représente (en tout cas pour ce "lui" dont le narrateur parle).
La comparaison donne aussi à Napoléon une dimension de messie, de sauveur.